# Как сделать картинки внутри блоки отзывчивыми?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, вновь вынужден обратиться за советом к магистрам верстки
На этот раз дело снова в картинках, хотел сделать небольшую секцию с флекс-элементами - картинка, а справа/слева текст. Но картинки никак не хотят принимать надлежащий вид, если указывать высоту и ширину в html - не помогает, сделал wrapper для картинки, задал максимальную ширину и высоту - тоже не помогает. Понемногу голова закипает, помогите, если не трудно. Как сделать картинки responsive и чтобы они корректно отображались?

```css
.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width:1170px){
    .container {
        max-width: 970px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:992px){
    .container {
        max-width: 750px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:767px){
    .container {
        max-width: none;
    }
}

.menu__item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/* --------------------------------------------------- */

.menu__content {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 100px;
}

/* --------------------------------------------------- */

.menu__wrapper {
    max-width: 650px;
    max-height: 700px;
    
}

.menu__img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="section__header">
            <h3 class="section__title">Меню</h3>
            <p class="section__text">КОФЕ, ЗАВТРАКИ, ВЫПЕЧКА</p>
        </div>

        <div class="menu">
            <div class="menu__item">
                <div class="menu__wrapper">
                    <img class="menu__img" src="https://picsum.photos/2500/4200" >
                </div>
                <div class="menu__content">
                    <h3 class="menu__title">Отличный кофе</h3>
                    <p class="menu__text">Наши бариста приготовят для Вас крипкий и ароматный кофе, чтобы проснуться утром. Или нежный и сладкий для поддержания энергии во время рабочего дня</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu__item">
                <div class="menu__content">
                    <h3 class="menu__title">Вкуснейшие завтраки</h3>
                    <p class="menu__text">Пока бариста будут варить для вас отменный кофе, закажите наши завтраки которые не оставят вас равнадушными на весь день!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="menu__wrapper">
                    <img class="menu__img" src="https://picsum.photos/3600/4500" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu__item">
                <div class="menu__wrapper">
                    <img class="menu__img" src="https://picsum.photos/1800/2500" >
                </div>
                <div class="menu__content">
                    <h3 class="menu__title">Свежайшая вепечка</h3>
                    <p class="menu__text">Возьмите с собой или к кофе нашу свежую выпечку. Лучший вариант чтобы сделать перекус во время работы или перерыва!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

P.S - странно, но в примере все работает корректно, а у меня картинки вылазят за границы блока, не соблюдают высоту заданную и вообще бунтуют как хотят!

Comment: проверьте, чтобы стили, которых в примере нет (если есть такие) не переопределяли свойства

Comment: высоту не указывайте вообще - пускай будет как есть - `автоматически под контент`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и сказал человек выше, нужно было убрать высоту изображения.

Вы хотели такой  результат?

```css
.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width:1170px){
    .container {
        max-width: 970px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:992px){
    .container {
        max-width: 750px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:767px){
    .container {
        max-width: none;
    }
}

.menu__item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/* --------------------------------------------------- */

.menu__content {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 100px;
}

/* --------------------------------------------------- */

.menu__wrapper {
    max-width: 650px;

    
}

.menu__img {
    display: block;
   
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
 <section class="section">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="section__header">
            <h3 class="section__title">Меню</h3>
            <p class="section__text">КОФЕ, ЗАВТРАКИ, ВЫПЕЧКА</p>
        </div>

        <div class="menu">
            <div class="menu__item">
                <div class="menu__wrapper">
                    <img class="menu__img" src="https://picsum.photos/2500/4200" >
                </div>
                <div class="menu__content">
                    <h3 class="menu__title">Отличный кофе</h3>
                    <p class="menu__text">Наши бариста приготовят для Вас крипкий и ароматный кофе, чтобы проснуться утром. Или нежный и сладкий для поддержания энергии во время рабочего дня</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu__item">
                <div class="menu__content">
                    <h3 class="menu__title">Вкуснейшие завтраки</h3>
                    <p class="menu__text">Пока бариста будут варить для вас отменный кофе, закажите наши завтраки которые не оставят вас равнадушными на весь день!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="menu__wrapper">
                    <img class="menu__img" src="https://picsum.photos/3600/4500" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu__item">
                <div class="menu__wrapper">
                    <img class="menu__img" src="https://picsum.photos/1800/2500" >
                </div>
                <div class="menu__content">
                    <h3 class="menu__title">Свежайшая вепечка</h3>
                    <p class="menu__text">Возьмите с собой или к кофе нашу свежую выпечку. Лучший вариант чтобы сделать перекус во время работы или перерыва!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: да, именно. Это странно, я ведь пробовал не задавать фикс. высоту, результат был тоже неудовлетворительный. Чем это объясняется?

Comment: Тем что вы задали высоту menu__img  и максимальную высоту menu__wrapper. В вашем случае их не нужно было задавать. При верстке вы использовали Bootstrap?

Comment: Нет, не использовал.

Comment: Но как тогда в случае если мне нужно сделать эти 3 блока конкретной высоты? Допустим мне нужны 3 блока высотой в 500px, в них картинки которые высотой в 1000px, мне ведь нужно будет задать высоту блока

Comment: Или например сделать блоки в 1000 пикселей, а картинки в 500?

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы картинка была адаптивной, то лучше высоту картинки не трогать. Попробуйте сделать блоки в 1000 пикселей и картинки в 500 и посмотрите, что получилось. Невозможно дать точного ответа, в вашем случае нужно экспериментировать.